# Show 3 items in swipper

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I saw this sample code on flutter [swipper](https://github.com/best-flutter/flutter_swiper) (flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6). I want to show 3 items like the default swipper instead of 1 item while retaining the swipe animation.

[image: 3 items].

**Currently only 1 item show on custom layout**.[image: custom layout].

```
 new Swiper(
  layout: SwiperLayout.CUSTOM,
  customLayoutOption: new CustomLayoutOption(
      startIndex: -1,
      stateCount: 3
  ).addRotate([
    -45.0/180,
    0.0,
    45.0/180
  ]).addTranslate([
    new Offset(-370.0, -40.0),
    new Offset(0.0, 0.0),
    new Offset(370.0, -40.0)
  ]),
  itemWidth: 300.0,
  itemHeight: 200.0,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: new Center(
        child: new Text("$index"),
      ),
    );
  },
  viewportFraction: 0.6,
  itemCount: 10)
```

Comment: yama na te hahhhah

Answer (score 0):

you need the `viewportFraction` parameter here

```
Swiper(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new Image.network(
      "http://via.placeholder.com/288x188",
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    );
  },
  itemCount: 10,
  viewportFraction: 0.8,
  scale: 0.9,
)
```

Comment: Already tried adding viewportFraction still the same result.